# Add new dropdown option Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to add new option in the select dropdown with jquery. For example I need to add: "--" in all three dropdown's after this: `<option value="">-</option>`. My code is:

```
<dd class="birth">
    <select id="options_6054_day" class="product-custom-option datetime-picker validation-passed" onchange="opConfig.reloadPrice()" style="width: auto;" title="" name="options[6054][day]">
        <option value="">-</option>
        <option value="1">01</option>
        <option value="2">02</option>
        <option value="3">03</option>
        <option value="4">04</option>
        <option value="5">05</option>
        <option value="6">06</option>
        <option value="7">07</option>
        <option value="8">08</option>
        <option value="9">09</option>
        <option value="10">10</option>
    </select>
    <select id="options_6054_month" class="product-custom-option datetime-picker validation-passed" onchange="opConfig.reloadPrice()" style="width: auto;" title="" name="options[6054][month]">
        <option value="">-</option>
        <option value="1">01</option>
        <option value="2">02</option>
        <option value="3">03</option>
        <option value="4">04</option>
        <option value="5">05</option>
        <option value="6">06</option>
        <option value="7">07</option>
        <option value="8">08</option>
        <option value="9">09</option>
        <option value="10">10</option>
        <option value="11">11</option>
        <option value="12">12</option>
    </select>
    <select id="options_6054_year" class="product-custom-option datetime-picker validation-passed" onchange="opConfig.reloadPrice()" style="width: auto;" title="" name="options[6054][year]">
        <option value="">-</option>
        <option value="2016">2016</option>
    </select>
</dd>
```

Comment: `$('#idofselect').append('<option>--</option>')`

Comment: and after the first option?

Comment: `$('#idofselect').find('option:nth-child(1)').after('<option>--</option>')`

Comment: Is perfect guradio, can you add your Answer and I will vote you, can you tell me something please, how I can select this by default for all three dropdowns? I need this new vaule to be selected by default

Comment: added description and a sample to add using class you can comment if something is unclear i will do my best to explain :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$('#idofselect').find('option:nth-child(1)').after('<option>--</option>')`

1. **$('#idofselect')** -> Id of the select you want to add the option. **If you want to add on all three you can use class that is common on
   all three** *(added sample for class)*
2. **.find('option:nth-child(1)')** -> look for the first option within the selected select
3. [.after()](http://api.jquery.com/after/) -> Description: Insert content, specified by the
   parameter, after each element in the set of matched elements.

```js
$('.select').find('option:nth-child(1)').after('<option>--</option>')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="options_6054_day" class="product-custom-option datetime-picker validation-passed select" onchange="opConfig.reloadPrice()" style="width: auto;" title="" name="options[6054][day]">
        <option value="">-</option>
        <option value="1">01</option>
        <option value="2">02</option>
        <option value="3">03</option>
        <option value="4">04</option>
        <option value="5">05</option>
        <option value="6">06</option>
        <option value="7">07</option>
        <option value="8">08</option>
        <option value="9">09</option>
        <option value="10">10</option>
    </select>
    <select id="options_6054_month" class="product-custom-option datetime-picker validation-passed select" onchange="opConfig.reloadPrice()" style="width: auto;" title="" name="options[6054][month]">
        <option value="">-</option>
        <option value="1">01</option>
        <option value="2">02</option>
        <option value="3">03</option>
        <option value="4">04</option>
        <option value="5">05</option>
        <option value="6">06</option>
        <option value="7">07</option>
        <option value="8">08</option>
        <option value="9">09</option>
        <option value="10">10</option>
        <option value="11">11</option>
        <option value="12">12</option>
    </select>
    <select id="options_6054_year" class="product-custom-option datetime-picker validation-passed select" onchange="opConfig.reloadPrice()" style="width: auto;" title="" name="options[6054][year]">
        <option value="">-</option>
        <option value="2016">2016</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: thank you so much, there is a small thing, the last dropdown select option need the value to be with 4 characters, so first must have -- and the last must have ----. is there anyway to change this?

Comment: @RobertD sorry i dont understand the question can you please elaborate last option to be added should be ---? meaning first is - second is -- ?

Comment: at the very bottom select we have this  <option value="2016">2016</option>, so I need to add here <option>----</option>

Comment: add only 1 ? on the last? i will make a demo you can check

Comment: so the first two select must have -- and the last must have four ----

Comment: i sort of understand give me a minute i will create a demo for dynamic solution

Comment: I think this is it, but you can select the new options by default?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109018/discussion-between-guradio-and-robertd).

Comment: Hi guradio, I have small issue with our new code, you have one minute?

Comment: @RobertD yes what happened?

Comment: I need you :) we can talk in chat?

Comment: Hi guradio, you have one minute?

Comment: we can talk in chat for a few minutes?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add option after first option then I think this will help.

```
$("select option").eq(0).after("<option>--</option")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$("select option").each(function(){
   if(this.index == 0){
      $(this).after("<option>--</option")
   }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
$(function() {
    $('.product-custom-option').find('option:nth-child(1)').after($('<option></option>').attr("value", '--').text('--'));
})
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/mayank_shubham/6Laee4mo/)

`'option:nth-child(1)'` will select the first option child of select.

`.after()` will add whatever you write in it after the selected element.

`.attr()` will allow you to set the attributes of option.

`.text()` will allow you to add text to option field.